# C++ pyramid of numbers

Tags: c++, fstream

I need to write a program where it takes 2 integers from a file. Then it has to make a pyramid from those 2 numbers. It has to look like this:

[image]

I've wrote the code and it works as I want to, bet I can't think of a way how make it look a pyramid like.

Here's how it looks when I do it:

[image]

And this is my code:

```
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

    int main(){

        ifstream inFile("Duomenys.txt");
        ofstream outFile("Rezultatai.txt");
        int N,M,smth,suma=0;

        inFile >> N >> M;
        smth=N;

        while(N<=M){
            for(int i=smth;i<=N;i++){
                outFile<<i<<" ";
                suma+=i;
                if(i==N){
                    for(int i=N-1;i>=smth;i--){
                        outFile<<i<<" ";
                        suma+=i;
                    }
                }
            }
            outFile<<endl;
            N++;
        }
        outFile<<endl<<"Skaiciu suma: "<<suma;

        inFile.close();
        outFile.close();
        return 0;
    }
```

So my question would be, how to make it that my answer would be shaped in pyramid like in example?

Comment: Compute the width of the final row upfront, and then use that information to centre each row.

Comment: I'd like to know how to do that either <.<

Comment: You might also want to take a look at the `width` parameter.

Comment: Well... think. Do you know how many numbers there are in the last row? Do you know how much space each number takes up?

Comment: Just assume a monospaced font (true enough for 99% of all terminals) and you can just count the number of chars per line as the "width".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <assert.h>

using namespace std;

template <class T>
int numDigits(T number)
{
    int digits = 0;
    while (number) {
        number /= 10;
        digits++;
    }
    return digits;
}

int main()
{
    ifstream inFile("Duomenys.txt");
    ofstream outFile("Rezultatai.txt");
    int N,M,smth,suma=0;

    inFile >> N >> M;
    smth=N;

    // assuming positive numbers
    assert(N>=0 && M>=0);
    // this will be the size of each printed number
    int nd = numDigits<int>(M)+1;

    while(N<=M){
        for(int i=N;i<=M;i++)
            outFile << setw(nd) << " ";
        for(int i=smth;i<=N;i++){
            outFile << setw(nd) << i;
            suma+=i;
            if(i==N){
                for(int i=N-1;i>=smth;i--){
                    outFile << setw(nd) << i;
                    suma+=i;
                }
            }
        }
        outFile<<endl;
        N++;
    }
    outFile<<endl<<"Skaiciu suma: "<<suma;

    inFile.close();
    outFile.close();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This was working if all numbers were printed in an unique string

Answer (score 0):

```
inFile >> N >> M;
        smth=N;

        while(N<=M){
            for(int position=0;position<(M-N);position++){  // doesn't work if M<N obviously
                for(int digit=(smth+position);digit;digit=digit/10){
                    outFile<<" ";
                }
                outFile<<" "; // this is to complement the spacer for each digit in your code
            }
            for(int i=smth;i<=N;i++){
                outFile<<i<<" ";
                ...
```

Answer (score 0):

First you must compute your second number's digit count. It's so easy. Then you can calculate the depth of concluded pyramid using: (second number- first number)+1. After that you can be sure that in the last row, the max digit count you will have is ((second number - first number)*2+1)*digit count=x of pyramid's head. So you should print the head of pyramid at (x,y)=(x of pyramid's head, ....)

Answer (score 0):

To determine the length of the last row you can either write your output to an `std::stringstream` and get the length with `myStrStream.str().size()` (and afterwards print the contents of your string stream to `std::cout` or your outFile) or you can count the length of all items of the last line separately and then sum then up, including spaces. I think the first approach is simpler.

The easiest approach might be backtracking.

Answer (score 0):

This also depends on the digits that every number have.
Assuming that every number has two digits, is enough to add a certain number of space for each iteration.
This number in your case is 5 during the first iteration, and ends up being zero:

```
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int main(){

    ifstream inFile("Duomenys.txt");
    ofstream outFile("Rezultatai.txt");
    int N,M,smth,suma=0;

    inFile >> N >> M;
    smth=N;

    while(N<=M){
        for(int i=smth;i<=N;i++){
            outFile<<i<<" ";
            suma+=i;
            if(i==N){
                for(int i=N;i<M;i++)
                    cout << "  ";
                for(int i=N-1;i>=smth;i--){
                    outFile<<i<<" ";
                    suma+=i;
                }
            }
        }
        outFile<<endl;
        N++;
    }
    outFile<<endl<<"Skaiciu suma: "<<suma;

    inFile.close();
    outFile.close();
    return 0;
}
```

An alternative is to use iomanip's setw, but this case you have to write all numbers in a string and print the whole string each time.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<fstream>
using namespace std;
ofstream outFile("output");
void printSpace(int a){
    string spaces(a,' ');
    outFile<<spaces;
}
int main(){
    int N=1,M=11,smth=4,suma=0;
    int l=2*(M-N);
    while(N<=M){
        printSpace(l);
        for(int i=smth;i<=N;i++){
            outFile<<i<<" ";
            suma+=i;
            if(i==N){
                for(int i=N-1;i>=smth;i--){
                    outFile<<i<<" ";
                    suma+=i;
                }
            }
        }
        l-=2;
        outFile<<endl;
        N++;
    }
    outFile<<endl<<"Skaiciu suma: "<<suma;

    outFile.close();
    return 0;
}
```